# Why predicates and functions are not explicitly separated in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, first-order-logic

Consider [this](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/hZCmjVdq.swinb) Prolog program:

```
a(1).
b(X) :- X.
```

This is valid in SWI Prolog. And the following queries give desirable (at first glance) results without any warnings:

```
?- b(a(1)).
true

?- b(a(2)).
false
```

And then it is unclear for me, why this is allowed.

Fact `a(1).` says that **predicate** `a/1` is true with argument `1`.

Query `b(a(1))` asks if predicate `b/1` is true with `a(1)` **function** value. When this query is resolved, `a(1)` is checked as **predicate**, however it was taken from predicate argument context which should allow only **terms** there.

So different concepts are messed here. We have predicates which may be true or false depending on their arguments. And we have symbolic functions which are some abstract (symbolic) values defined by functor and arguments. The function does not necessary return true or false, it may be completely different domain. The only action with function here might be using it as a term in predicates to state some rules and facts about its value.

For me it looks like rule `b(X) :- X.` should not be compilable because variable X was firstly used in term context, and then in predicate context. Probably, variables should not be allowed at all in predicate context.

Isn't this some fundamental design inconsistency from math point of view?

Comment: A function takes an input and returns an output, there are no functions here. `b/1` is a **meta-predicate** that relates a predicate to it's truth value. So query `b(a(1))` asks if `b/1` is true with `a(1)` **predicate** value. From the maths point of view, meta-predicates are akin to second-order logic.

Comment: The distinction You are making as-if one of these us a predicate and the other a function is incorrect . "a(1)" is as much a function as is "b(X)" . The correct distinction is that a predicate is  a function but specifically constrained to return either "true" or "false" .

Comment: @Kintalken Yes, I understand this, and that is the point, that they are from different domains and cannot be mixed. However Paul Brown comment explained it a bit, I was not aware of meta-predicates concept. Here is another better example: `a(b(1)). c(X) :- X. d(1).`
Query `c(b(1)).` fails, `d(b(1))` returns false. In one case `b(1)` is treated as predicate, in other as function.

Comment: The query ``d(b(1))`` does not cause ``d`` to treat ``b(1)`` as either a function or a predicate : the query simply does not match any ``d(_)`` at all so ``d`` never has a chance to do anything . BTW , the term ``function`` does not have a canonical meaning : it is certainly of different meaning betwixt compsci and maths and logics ; and within logics is used in several incompatible ways .

Comment: @PaulBrown wrote "A function takes an input and returns an output, there are no functions here" -- that is the maths definition , but "input" called "domain" output called "image"/or/"range' ; maths also requiring that the "output" is constrained to one possible value . In Prolog such "function"s are found on the right-hand-side of the ``is`` operator :: for example __sqrt__ in ``X is 1 + sqrt(Y)`` .

Comment: An example with good description of "function" as used in logics is in the 2nd paragraph here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_(artificial_intelligence) .

Basically the idea is that whilst the term "angry(tom)" is a __predicate__ (thus true or false) stating that tom is angry ; the __predicate__ can be __reified__ to become a __function__ if it becomes the argument of another __predicate__ [*1] : thus with ``if(angry(tom),true)`` :: ``if`` is now the __predicate__ and ``angry(tom)`` is a __function__ .
[*1] this seems germane to the OP .

Comment: In compsci a __function__ is distinct from a __procedure__ (only) in that a __function__ has a return value but a __procedure__ does not have a return value . A __procedure__ is executed in a **statement** context whereas a **function** is executed in a **expression** context . In Prolog a __predicate__ is more like a __procedure__ less like a __function__ , with additional capacity of indicating success/or/failure to the calling context ; also ability to push newly discovered values for arguments/and/or sub-components of arguments because arguments are passed by-reference not passed by-value.

Comment: `angry(tom)` is not a function, it's a relational fluent, which would be resolved by reintroducing the situation: `holds(angry(tom), s) = angry(tom, s)`. The `if/2` example would be reduced to `angry(tom, s)`: the relationship between Tom, 'angry', and the situation. A functional fluent would be something like `location(tom, s)`, it doesn't contain an argument for the location itself, it is expected to return the value of Tom's location in the situation. We don't have these in Prolog, but McCarthy was noted for LISP alongside Situation Calculus and many other AI innovations.